# How can I display the author's profile with a particular view mode on a node using display suite

Tags: display-suite

I'd like to show the author's profile on a node. I'm not using Views to display a single node. That node would display through an altered display of the 'default' view mode using Display Suite. Now I see the fields: author, user picture. But the author field doesn't allow me to select a custom made display suite 'user view mode'. I only have the possibility to select "author linked to profile" or "author" for the settings.

Comment: This could be done via DS Dynamic Fields (https://www.previousnext.com.au/blog/creating-custom-display-suite-fields-or-how-i-learned-stop-worrying-and-use-hookdsfieldsinfo). However, I would simply do this in a hook_preprocess_node() function.